# How do I take minecraft blocks from nowhere?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing minecraft and a player looked at a block and he suddenly had it in his hand. How did he do that? (He was in creative by the way)

Answer (score 6):

The `Pick Block` key, bound to mouse 3 by default (middle mouse button on most mice.) Just look at the block and press whatever `Pick Block` is bound to, and it'll be in your hand. Of course, you'll need creative mode.

See also, [this Minecraft Wiki article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Controls#Pick_Block)

Comment: Well I have a laptop which means I dont have a mouse. Any more advice?

Comment: Set the control in options>controls to something like P.